# Is there a way to detect if the user hide a div through firebug and chrome?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, firebug, layer

i´m working on a site where one function is hidden through a layer (this is only available for registrated users, please register).

The main site is a profile that should be not accessible. Some users could try to hide the layer so my question is if there is a function i can handle to detect if the user hides the layer so i can display it again.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more please? Is there a function that will detect users action if s/he hid a div?

Comment: You cannot prevent View Source in web

Answer (score 4):

Hiding the HTML for a feature is not a good way to control user access to that feature.  It will certainly be broken.  You will not win.

Implement user access where it belongs... on the web server, where the HTML is generated.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering why someone would want to do what Michael is trying to do... Your answer is clear.

Comment: you could still generate the html on client side. Just the client ask the server what to display (only the data)

Comment: Well... that's writing to the DOM on the client side after getting permission from the server to do so.  That's consistent with what I said... control access on the server side.  If you generate straight HTML and send it down the pipe or use something like an Ajax call to fetch additional parts, you are not fundamentally changing the fact that the server controls access.

Answer (score 0):

You should absolutely not be doing this client side. Almost every solution I can think of for this is easily avoidable. If the user isn't registered, don't include registered user functionality, even if in the browser the content is invisible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to hide something using javascript (as your tag says) then its a bad idea. No matter what you try to hide in JS the user would eventually be able to see it. That is why it is called a Client side language. Try porting the logic to php(or any serverside language) which would make sure that the user can never see your logic in whatsoever way.

Comment: Why PHP?  Any server-side technology will do.

Comment: @EricJ.I thought of giving an example.. Did not literally mean php.

Comment: then it's not hidden, it's just not there, on client side. A client js application could dynamically fetch what is visible for a given user (registered or not).  You don't need to build your web app on server side (php, jsp, etc.) for doing that.

Comment: Well it could be done but the design would be a little skewed. Server side languages are supposed to be used for these.

Comment: @unludo: If you allow _JavaScript_ to determine "yep, this guy is a registered user, call back to http://domain.com/GetRegisteredUserStuff", then I can edit and change the JavaScript from `if (isRegistered)` to `if (!isRegistered)` and access content I should not.  It doesn't matter whether or not you obfuscate the JavaScript... it is vulnerable to attack.

Comment: @EricJ.That's not what I am saying. JS asks server, here are my credentials, give me my data. The server is doing the filtering. But JS is doing the rendering. Look at dojo toolkit, emberjs, javascriptMVC. This is what I am talking about anf is IMO future of web apps.

Comment: @unludo: If javascript is *strictly* used for rendering then the decision of whether to display the content goes to the server as you have said. And the OP is talking whether he could hide and detect unhide in javascript, about the hidden layer that he is hiding for registered and non-registered users. Anything you try to hide, will eventually be revealed (literally). So the only soultion is to forbit the access and ergo to implement it in server side language.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure, if i am completely off, but i would try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   setInterval(function(){
     var div = $('#theAlwaysVisibleDiv');
     div.show();
   },1000);
});
```

One way to reproduce it, might be to change the divs visibility through the developer console, it should reappear after a second?